# How to merge two overlapping dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

I need to write code that takes in new dataframes and merges them with an existing one. The rows are ordered by date but unfortunately there is often an overlap. E.g.

```
    Transaction_Date    transaction
1330    26/05/2017  2997.71
1327    30/05/2017  -1394.59
1329    30/05/2017  -2650.00
1328    30/05/2017  664.00
```

and

```
1329    30/05/2017  -2650.00
1328    30/05/2017  664.00
1326    31/05/2017  374.79
1324    01/06/2017  -160.00
1325    01/06/2017  -27.62
```

Say the first dataframe is called `df1` and the second is called `df2`, how can I merge them to get rid of the duplicates in the overlapping part?

The expected result should be:

```
    Transaction_Date    transaction
1330    26/05/2017  2997.71
1327    30/05/2017  -1394.59
1329    30/05/2017  -2650.00
1328    30/05/2017  664.00
1326    31/05/2017  374.79
1324    01/06/2017  -160.00
1325    01/06/2017  -27.62
```

Comment: What is expected output?

Comment: @jezrael Added now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe need [`concat`](http://pands.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) with remove duplicates by index values by [`duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.duplicated.html) with [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = pd.concat([df1, df2])
df = df[~df.index.duplicated()]
```

Full example:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'date': pd.date_range('2018-01-01', periods=7, freq='12H'),
    'index': [1330, 1327, 1329, 1328, 1326, 1324, 1325]
}).set_index('index')

df1 = df.iloc[[0,1,2,3]]
df2 = df.iloc[[2,3,4,5,6]]

df = pd.concat([df1, df2])
df = df[~df.index.duplicated()]

print(df)
```

Returns:

```
                     date
index                    
1330  2018-01-01 00:00:00
1327  2018-01-01 12:00:00
1329  2018-01-02 00:00:00
1328  2018-01-02 12:00:00
1326  2018-01-03 00:00:00
1324  2018-01-03 12:00:00
1325  2018-01-04 00:00:00
```

Comment: @Anton vBR - Thank you